# Firebase Auth CNAME update requirement without top domain

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-authentication

I've recently received an email from Firebase, that in order to use authorization service email templates without them falling in spam folder, I need to add new CNAME records to custom domain defined for that Firebase app.

However those records are in format: **firebase2._domainkey** and not **firebase2._domainkey.my-custom-domain-name-something.com**

I didn't know it's possible to add a record in DNS that doesn't involve domain name itself.

Is this a documentation error or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, you only have to include the partial domain. The fully qualified hostname will have the custom-domain-name-something.com appended to it.

[You can check out this small tuto for more info](https://o365info.com/how-to-create-the-cname-records-for-outbound-dkim-signing-using-godaddy-dns-office-365-part-8-10/)